# Determine the date format by locale with clj-time

Tags: date, clojure, clj-time

I have been searching for this for quite a while now through Google and I couldn't find an ultimate solution with clj-time. I want to format a date automatically by the locale, like in [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/DateFormatwithLocale.htm) or [here](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-format-date-using-a-locale-based-format/). How would I do this using clj-time?

Thanks & Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `with-locale` (http://clj-time.github.io/clj-time/doc/clj-time.format.html#var-with-locale)

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as time] '[clj-time.format :as fmt])
(import '[java.util Locale])

(def custom-formatter (fmt/formatters :rfc822))
(def ja-formatter (fmt/with-locale custom-formatter (Locale. "ja")))
(fmt/unparse ja-formatter (time/date-time 2010 10 3))
> "日, 03 10 2010 00:00:00 +0000"
```

-UPDATE-

Example of usage of joda-time DateTimeFormat:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as time] '[clj-time.format :as fmt])
(import '[java.util Locale])
(import '[org.joda.time.format DateTimeFormat])
(def custom-formatter (DateTimeFormat/longDate))
(def ja-formatter (fmt/with-locale custom-formatter (Locale. "ja")))
(fmt/unparse ja-formatter (time/date-time 2010 10 3))
"2010/10/03"
(def us-formatter (fmt/with-locale custom-formatter (Locale. "us")))
(fmt/unparse us-formatter (time/date-time 2010 10 3))
"October 3, 2010"
```

Comment: I tried that and it works with rfc822, but what if I want the format "Monday, October 29, 2014" and the respective formattings in Korea, China, Germany etc.? For now I have gone with this solution: **(.format (SimpleDateFormat/getDateInstance 0 (Locale/US) (t.coerce/to-date clj-time-date))** - and it gives me the correctly formatted dates for the different languages.

Comment: you may want to build DateTimeFormat from Joda since clj-time is a wrapper around joda-time. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html